# Simple Linear Regression about Bodyweight

Tags: statistics, regression

Suppose that a random sample of 200 twenty-year-old men is selected
from a population and that these men’s height and weight are recorded.
A regression of weight on height yields

[Regression Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iag30.png)

The task is:
Suppose that instead of measuring weight and height in pounds
and inches these variables are measured in centimeters and
kilograms. What are the regression estimates from this new
centimeter-kilogram regression?
(1 inch = 2.54 cm and 1 pound = 0.4536 kg)
(Give all results, estimated coefficients, R2
, and SER.)

Comment: $r$ and $r^2$ (sometimes denoted in regression printouts as `R2` or `R-sq`) will not change because $r$ is a dimensionless quantity.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer ?

Comment: Yes! I understand that R2 isn't changing, but what about the other coefficients?